# Why does this time unit conversion return zeroes?

Tags: java, math, integer, floating-point, long-integer

I am experiencing a problem with the code below. It's converting milliseconds to months, days, hours, and minutes.

```
long diffms = date2l - date1l; //The result here is in milliseconds; The value of date2l - date1l are different
long diff_minute = diffms / 60000;

long diff_hour = diff_minute / 60; float diff_minute_now = (diff_minute % 1) * 60; int dmn = (int) diff_minute_now;
long diff_day = diff_hour / 24; float diff_hour_now = (diff_hour % 1) * 24; int dhn = (int) diff_hour_now;
long diff_month = diff_day / 30; float diff_day_now = (diff_day % 1) * 30;  int ddn = (int) diff_day_now;   

diffe = new LabelField
("Remaining Time : " + Long.toString(diff_month) + " month(s) " 
                    + Integer.toString(ddn) + " day(s) " 
                    + Integer.toString(dhn) + " hour(s) "
                    + Integer.toString(dmn) + " minute(s)");
add(diffe);
```

Why are the result values all zeroes?

EDIT: 
@BicycleDude I modify your code into:

```
long diffms = date2l - date1l;
long ts = diffms / 1000;

long mo = ts / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30;
long d = (ts - mo * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60) / (60 * 60 * 24);
long h = (ts - d * 24 * 60 * 60) / (60 * 60);
long m = (ts - h * 60 * 60) / 60;
```

But the hours doesn't work

Comment: What values are you using for `date2l` and `date1l`? If `date2l == date1l`, you would expect all of the values to be 0.

Comment: it's the time from the calendar in milliseconds format. They are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to base my answer on the edited part of the code, since BicycleDude has already pointed out what was wrong with the modulo operations.

```
long diffms = date2l - date1l; //difference in ms
long ts = diffms / 1000; //total difference in seconds

long mo = ts / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30; //(1)
long d = (ts - mo * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60) / (60 * 60 * 24); //follows on because of (1)
long h = (ts - d * 24 * 60 * 60) / (60 * 60); //follows on because of (1)
long m = (ts - h * 60 * 60) / 60; //follows on because of (1)
```

Alright, I thought there would be multiple problems, but I think (*think*, I'm probably missing something...) that the main error is coming from your calculation of months, which I denoted in the code by the comment `(1)`. You can't calculate the difference in months like that.

Why? What about if there was more than one month in differences? Wouldn't you need to divide by 31, instead? Or if it was a leap year? You'd need to divide by 29 if it was February. Since integer division doesn't round or account for decimals, you can get inaccuracies in your difference-in-months calculation. It's probably best if you instead use the differences in hours to calculate the difference in days, and from there you can figure out the difference in months. (**Edit**: I think you'd also need to take into account the factors I mentioned above when calculating the difference in months from the difference in days, by checking what your "origin" and "target" dates are, though I wouldn't be too sure of writing it myself at thie stage...)

Since you have a problem with the way you calculate the difference in months, and you use the erroneous value to calculate the difference in days, I think this results in the error propagating down to some of your other values (eg. the difference in hours).

**EDIT**

Okay, I mucked around with the code a bit more. As I noted earlier, your months calculation was dangerous and affected your days calculation, which potentially introduced errors later on.

With the example you provided in the comments, your code had a discrepancy of 3 days in the number of days. (The example was 19 January 2012 to 3 May 2012). I ran this against BicycleDude's code and it was fine.

I'll repost the code, and I've just added one line to find the number of days, based on how many hours have passed.

```
long h = ts / 60 / 60; // hour part
long m = (ts - h * 60 * 60) / 60; // minute part
long s = (ts - h * 60 * 60 - m * 60); // second part
long d = h / 24;
```

If you like to make it so that you can read that "there are `w` days, `x` hours, `y` minutes and `z` seconds between date2l and date1l", you could do something like this:

```
long date2l = Timestamp.valueOf("2012-05-03 05:30:10").getTime();
long date1l = Timestamp.valueOf("2012-01-19 00:00:00").getTime();
long diffms = date2l - date1l; //difference in ms
long diff_seconds = diffms / 1000; //total difference in seconds
long diff_mins = diff_seconds / 60; //total difference in minutes
long diff_hours = diff_mins / 60; //total difference in hours
long diff_days = diff_hours / 24; //total difference in days

long x = (diff_seconds - diff_days * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60);
long y = ((diff_seconds - (diff_hours * 60 * 60))) / 60;
long z = ((diff_seconds - (diff_mins * 60)));
long w = diff_days;

System.out.println(w + " " + x + " " + y + " " + z);
```

And it appears to work.

I haven't figured out the months part because that's a lot more non-trivial, but yeah. This kinda works?

Comment: It's the same. I got the result 13 days 0 hours 18720 minutes. Can't say the value of ts though, cos I dont know it myself. date1l and date2l are taken from a calendar function. But I am counting today (19 January 2012) to 1 February 2012

Comment: Ah, okay. Let me re-examine the code, then...I'm pretty sure what I noticed earlier will hold, though it might not be noticeable since there's less than a month's difference in the dates you're checking.

Comment: @blahman I put today until 3 May 2012 and it returns 102 days 0 hours 151200 minutes

Comment: Sorry, that took awhile. I was trying to figure out how to do the conversion because I hit a mental block. I'll try and comment and make the code simpler in my next edit.

Comment: yepp... I put 19 January 2012 to 1 February 2012 and it only shows 13 days 0 hours o minutes

Comment: That's because that's how many days, hours and minutes are between `2012-01-19 00:00:00` and `2012-02-01 00:00:00`. I'm pretty sure that's what is being calculated, right? The difference between two dates? Since there are no hours or minutes components, it's just in terms of the days at the moment.

Comment: @blahman date1l is actually the milliseconds format of now time so time actually counts right? After all the method is .getTime()

Comment: Okay, I just gave the code I posted a quick run, and I didn't get a problem. I changed `date1l` to `System.currentTimeMillis()` and kept `date2l` as `2012-05-03 05:30:10`. My output was `104 14 56 41`. I'm not sure why you're getting `0`s unless I'm looking at something different to you.

Comment: @blahman it works! Seems like the problem is I forgot to include HH and mm in my date format. Thanks very much :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you ^^

Answer (score 5):

'anything % 1' will return 0. it's probably not what you intended.

1. The variables you divide initially are type long. So their results will also be long. (e.g. 12345 / 100 = 123 not 123.45).
2. The modulo operator works on remainder on division of integers. (e.g. 12345 % 100 = 45).
3. The algorithm you supplied doesn't extract day, month, hour, minute, second in the manner you expected. It requires rework before it's correct.

I've reworked the formulas with the assumption there are 31 days in a month:

```
long diffms = date2l - date1l;
long mo = (diffms / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 31);
long d = (diffms / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) % 31;
long h = (diffms / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
long m = (diffms / 1000 / 60) % 60;
long s = (diffms / 1000) % 60;
```

Comment: Well, let's say the value of diff_minute is 100,000. To make it to hours, I have to divide it by 60, and the result will be 1667.67. The value of 0.67 should be multiplied by 60 to get the last value of minute right? So the way to do that is not diff_minute % 1?

Comment: No.  x % y will divide x by y and then return the integer remainder of that operation.  7 % 2 is 1, 8 % 2 is 0.  If you want 0.67 times 60, that's 0.67 * 60.

Comment: That's why I use % 1, cos the remainder will be the decimal value. Or is it not?

Comment: @Anthony because most your variables are typed long, you've already removed precision that would have been useful to you.

Comment: Anthony, the modulo operator only works on integer remainders. `i % 1` will always be `0` because `%` is a binary operation defined on a field of integers (I might be remembering my maths wrongly). Anyways, `long` story `short`, you can't use modulo and expect a non-integer value as your result. Sorry for the terrible puns.

Answer (score 2):

The [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class provides factory methods that simplifies most of your work:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*; 


// First, calculate the total difference in each unit
long diffDays = MILLISECONDS.toDays(diffMs);
long diffHours = MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffMs);
long diffMinutes = MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffMs);
long diffSeconds = MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffMs);

// Next, calculate the differences
long months = diffDays / 30;
long days = diffDays - 30 * months;
long hours = diffHours - DAYS.toHours(diffDays);
long minutes = diffMinutes - HOURS.toMinutes(diffHours);
long seconds = diffSeconds - MINUTES.toSeconds(diffMinutes);
```